# How to calculate Height-Based-Priority on Modulo scheduling?

Tags: compiler-construction, multiprocessing, scheduling, modulo

I analyze the modulo scheduling.

In 'Iterative Modulo scheduling', they normally use Height-Based-Priority for getting priority.

Basically, I know the formula of getting HBP.
In cyclic case,

---

```
 Height R(X) is 0(if X has no successor) or 

 MAX(Height(Y) + EffDelay(X, y)) && Y
```

is included into X's successor. (otherwise.)

---

But If we don't know successor's Height, how can we get that current height?

For example,

(1) Node 4 is exit node.

(2) Node2 is connected to node3 and  node3 is successor of node 2.
(also maybe we need to connect with node2 and exit node as pseudo edg).

(3) If we want to get node2's height, but we don't know node3's height.

So how can the be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Rau proposes a reursive HeightR function including a fix-point iteration in his full length IMS paper.

https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/94/HPL-94-115.pdf Algorithm 10, Page 39.

I used it for my implementation and it finds a feasible schedule for all graphes I checked.